# ValueError: could not convert string to float:'Udah stres bgt muka udah beruntusan'

Tags: python, svm

I'm trying make a simple classification.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
classifier = SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state =0) 
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I tried making classification i got this error :
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Udah stres bgt muka udah beruntusan'

This is my value error traceback

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-c2136a7032e7> in <module>
      2 from sklearn.svm import SVC
      3 classifier = SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state =0)
----> 4 classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    144         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64,
    145                          order='C', accept_sparse='csr',
--> 146                          accept_large_sparse=False)
    147         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    148 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    717                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
    718                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
--> 719                     estimator=estimator)
    720     if multi_output:
    721         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    494             try:
    495                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 496                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    497             except ComplexWarning:
    498                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __array__(self, dtype)
    946             warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=3)
    947             dtype = "M8[ns]"
--> 948         return np.asarray(self.array, dtype)
    949 
    950     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Please add code that creates `X_train`.

Answer (score 0):

Error is because of presence of `string` objects in your data which cannont be interpreted by the computer as it only understands numbers

Try converting `categorical` or `string` type data using the following two techniques

- `pd.get_dummies` [Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)
- `LabelEncoder` [Reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Comment: I've tried using pd.get_dummies but the result is still the same error